# Is it possible to trigger a datasource read of a kendo scrollview when scrolling to the left?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, scrollview, kendo-datasource

The datasource in a kendo scrollview (with serverPaging) will trigger a read (with skip & pageSize) when scrolling to the right. The view will notice when it is close to the end of the dataset and will update itself when the end of the full list is not yet reached.

Is it possible to trigger the same datasource read when scrolling to the left? My datasource does not always start at the beginning of the full list, so I want it to update itself when it is close to the beginning of the dataset, while not having reached the beginning of the full list yet.